# What's the best way to track dozens of App IDs and Provisioning Profiles?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, administration, app-id

I manage our Apple Developer and Enterprise accounts, along with both accounts' certs, App IDs, and Provisioning Profiles. There's dozens of them and we'd like to better track what vendor is working on what app, and what stage of development they're in. We're losing track of what should be removed after an app goes live or gets retired.

Any suggestions how to best keep track of Provisioning Profiles for dozens of (if not 100+) apps? With all the details for each cert, App ID, Prov. Profile, I'm thinking a DB is better than a spreadsheet. Anyone have experience with this? Is there a desktop (PC) app that could make this easier?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cupertino which you can use to manage all aspects of Dev center: https://github.com/nomad/Cupertino and then you can write a simple set of scripts to manage and track it.

EDIT: As for what to do with the data it all depends on the sort of control you want.  Simple shell scripts might suffice (and are better than persisting data that you don't need to) but without knowing your use cases in more detail it's hard to recommend more.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'm sorry I was too busy to notice you answered so quickly.